# Upper bound on trace of product of unitary and arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let the field be complex, $U$ be an $n\times n$ unitary matrix, $M$ be any $n\times n$ matrix, and $|M|$ denote the matrix formed by taking the absolute value of every entry of $M$.

Edited Question: What is the general upper bound on $|trace(UM)|$?

As asked previously, the following statement is false -

There exists a permutation matrix $\Pi$, such that $|trace(UM)|\leq trace(\Pi|M|)$

Counter-example: $U=[[1/2,(1+i\sqrt2)/2],[(1-i\sqrt2)/2,-1/2]]$, $M=[[1.1,0],[1,0]]$

Comment: Obvious counterexamples exist if $\Pi$ is always $I$. The inequality seems to hold for other specific values of 2x2 unitaries. Proving for general 2x2 unitaries seems to turn messy quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_iw_i^t$ be a singular value decomposition of $M$, i.e., $a_i\geq 0$, $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ and  $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ are orthonormal bases of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

If $U$ is a unitary matrix then $\{Uv_1,\ldots,Uv_n\}$ still is an orthornormal basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Thus, $|tr(UM)|=|tr(\sum_{i=1}^na_iUv_iw_i^t)|\leq\sum_{i=1}^na_i|tr(Uv_iw_i^t)|\leq \sum_{i=1}^na_i|Uv_i||w_i|\leq \sum_{i=1}^na_i$.

Let $U=\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{w_i}\ \overline{v_i}^t$. Notice that $U$ is unitary.

Now, $|tr(UM)|=|tr(\sum_{i=1}^na_iUv_iw_i^t)|=|tr(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\overline{w_i}w_i^t)|=\sum_{i=1}^na_i$.

Thus, a sharp upper bound for $|tr(UM)|$ is the sum of the singular values of $M$.

Comment: What are the spectral values of $M$? The absolute value of each eigenvalue of $M$?

Comment: @user193319 I meant singular value decomposition, instead of spectral decomposition. The $ai_s$ are the singular values of $M$, i.e., the square roots of the eigenvalues of $M\overline{M}^t$.

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example (to the previous question): $U=[[1/2,(1+i\sqrt2)/2],[(1-i\sqrt2)/2,-1/2]]$, $M=[[1.1,0],[1,0]]$